# Does c++ standard allow to call std::align with zero size and obtain a past-the-end pointer?

Tags: c++

Does [std::align](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) allow to be called with zero size and obtain an aligned pointer that may be a past-the-end pointer?

For [example:](https://godbolt.org/z/xcd8oWWdr)

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  alignas(16) char buffer[16];
  printf("buffer: %p ~ %p\n",
      static_cast<void*>(buffer),
      static_cast<void*>(buffer + sizeof(buffer)));
  void* start = buffer + 10;
  std::size_t space = 6;
  printf("start=%p space=%zu\n", start, space);
  void* result = std::align(8, 0, start, space); // call with size=0
  printf("result=%p start=%p space=%zu\n", result, start, space);
  // result is a pase-the-end pointer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does c++ standard allow to call std::align with zero size

Yes; there is no precondition disallowing zero size.

> and obtain a past-the-end pointer?

Obtaining a one-past-the-end pointer is allowed.